# How to package a command-line Python script?

Tags: python, setuptools

Suppose I have the following hello-world.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("Hello, world!")
```

How can I build a setup.py file that would install it to $PATH?

Comment: See the doc: https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html

Comment: http://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/path.html this should help you out.

Comment: @NikhilShinday: this does not relate to my question.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).  Also, you could just grab the source for another Python package that installs scripts in your `$PATH` and see how it works.